# Angular2: mouse event handling (movement relative to current position)

Tags: typescript, angular, mouseevent, rxjs, eventemitter

My user should be able to move (or rotate) an object by mouse in a canvas. When mouse events occur the screen coordinates are used to calculate the delta (direction and length) to the last event. Nothing special...

1. mousedown (get the first coordinate)
2. mousemove (get nth coordinate, calculate deltaXY, move object by deltaXY)
3. mouseup (same as step 2 and stop the mousemove and mouseup event handling)

After this chain of events it should be possible to repeat the same action.

This outdated example works as expected, after removing the `toRx` calls. But here the delta to the first coordinate is determined: [github.com:rx-draggable](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS)

Here is my effort to adapt the code from the example:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  providers: [Scene],
  template: '<canvas #canvas id="3dview"></canvas>'
})
export class Home {
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef;
  private scene: Scene;
  private mousedrag = new EventEmitter();
  private mouseup   = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
  private mousedown = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
  private mousemove = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
  private last: MouseEvent;
  private el: HTMLElement;

  @HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
  onMouseup(event: MouseEvent) { this.mouseup.emit(event); }

  @HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMousemove(event: MouseEvent) { this.mousemove.emit(event); }

  constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef, scene: Scene) {
    this.el = elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.scene = scene;
  }

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  mouseHandling(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('mousedown', event);
    this.last = event;
    this.mousemove.subscribe({next: evt => {
      console.log('mousemove.subscribe', evt);
      this.mousedrag.emit(evt);
    }});
    this.mouseup.subscribe({next: evt => {
      console.log('mousemove.subscribe', evt);
      this.mousedrag.emit(evt);
      this.mousemove.unsubscribe();
      this.mouseup.unsubscribe();
    }});
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('init');
    this.mousedrag.subscribe({
      next: evt => {
        console.log('mousedrag.subscribe', evt);
        this.scene.rotate(
            evt.clientX - this.last.clientX, 
            evt.clientY - this.last.clientY);
        this.last = evt;
      }
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

It works only for one cycle. After the `mouseup` event i got this error:

> Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "mousemove"
>
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ObjectUnsubscribedError
>
> ERROR CONTEXT: EventEvaluationErrorContext

The cancellation of the `mousemove` subscription does not work. The error is repeating for all following mousemoves.

Do you have an idea what is wrong with my code? Is there a different elegant approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe your problem lies in the difference between `unsubscribe()` and `remove(sub : Subscription)` on an `EventEmitter`. But it is possible to do it without the use of subscriptions (except the ones created by a `@HostListener`) and make it easy to read. I've rewritten your code a little. You might consider though placing your `mouseup` `event` on the `document` or `window`, otherwise you get weird behaviour if you release your mouse outside the canvas.

*Warning: untested code ahead*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    providers: [Scene],
    template: '<canvas #canvas id="3dview"></canvas>'
})
export class Home {
    @ViewChild('canvas') 
    canvas: ElementRef;

    private scene: Scene;
    private last: MouseEvent;
    private el: HTMLElement;

    private mouseDown : boolean = false;

    @HostListener('mouseup')
    onMouseup() {
        this.mouseDown = false;
    }

    @HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
    onMousemove(event: MouseEvent) {
        if(this.mouseDown) {
           this.scene.rotate(
              event.clientX - this.last.clientX,
              event.clientY - this.last.clientY
           );
           this.last = event;
        }
    }

    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    onMousedown(event) {
        this.mouseDown = true;
        this.last = event;
    }

    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, scene: Scene) {
        this.el = elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.scene = scene;
    }
}
```

Comment: your old code, which uses 'remove' did not work, you have any idea why? Do you know a good resource to learn that reactive stuff with angular2?

Comment: @Meiko Mmm, I didn't test the `remove`, but I did use it before like this and it worked. I have no good resources, and am just learning while playing :). Thank you for the accept. Glad i could help

Comment: Quick question, can you point me to documentation for HostListener that mentions ['$event']?  Trying to learn more about that.

Comment: What is this provider Scene where we should import that from?

Comment: @Gobi that's specific to the OP question. I assume it's a WebGL 3D scene reference, and probably a custom service for his app. You can ignore it

Answer (score 6):

The problem that you have is that the code is not reactive. In reactive programming all behaviors should be defined at decoration time and only one subscription is required.

Here is an example: [Angular2/rxjs mouse translation/rotation](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/Otz4l6/)

```
import {Component, NgModule, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule, ElementRef, MouseEvent} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMapTo';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [`
  canvas{
    border: 1px solid red;
  }`],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>translate/Rotate by mouse</h2>
      <canvas #canvas id="3dview"></canvas>
      <p>Translate by delta: {{relativeTo$|async|json}}</p>
      <p>Rotate by angle: {{rotateToAngle$|async|json}}</p>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App extends OnInit {

    @ViewChild('canvas') 
    canvas: ElementRef;

    relativeTo$: Observable<{dx:number, dy:number, start: MouseEvent}>;
    rotateToAngle$: Observable<{angle:number, start: MouseEvent}>;

    ngOnInit() {
      const canvasNE = this.canvas.nativeElement;

      const mouseDown$ = Observable.fromEvent(canvasNE, 'mousedown');
      const mouseMove$ = Observable.fromEvent(canvasNE, 'mousemove');
      const mouseUp$ = Observable.fromEvent(canvasNE, 'mouseup');

      const moveUntilMouseUp$= mouseMove$.takeUntil(mouseUp$);
      const startRotate$ = mouseDown$.switchMapTo(moveUntilMouseUp$.startWith(null));

      const relativePoint = (start: MouseEvent, end: MouseEvent): {x:number, y:number} => 
      (start && end && {
        dx: start.clientX - end.clientX,
        dy: start.clientY - end.clientY,
        start: start
      } || {});

      this.relativeTo$ = startRotate$
        .combineLatest(mouseDown$)
        .map(arr => relativePoint(arr[0],arr[1]));

      this.rotateToAngle$ = this.relativeTo$
        .map((tr) => ({angle: Math.atan2(tr.dy, tr.dx), start: tr.start}));

//      this.relativeTo$.subscribe(console.log.bind(console,'rotate:'));
//      this.rotateToAngle$.subscribe(console.log.bind(console,'rotate 0:'));
    }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```