# Angular 2/4 Image Cropping with mouse event

Tags: image, angular, mouse, crop

I am new to angular2/4. I am searching for angular package that could crop images using mouse events. I searched a lot but could find any thing. Hope you guys have one. Or give me some hints how to implement a good one.

I found some packages for image cropping but they were not very helpful in my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need include module on purejs. Plus add types for module and u can use module with interface.

I searched and find it

1. https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cropperjs

For mouse event read this post - [Angular2: mouse event handling (movement relative to current position)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056628/angular2-mouse-event-handling-movement-relative-to-current-position)

**UPDATED:**

You can use this module https://github.com/cstefanache/angular2-img-cropper

Answer (score 1):

for single image upload and crop https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper 
and for Multiple 
https://github.com/MMtechnolab/Angular-Typescript--2-8-Multiple-Image-Upload-and-Crop-.git
 check this
Demo: http://mmangimgcrop.gear.host/

I had Also same issue in Angular 8 so i made some changes in ngx-image-cropper, It allows user to upload multiple images as u can see in below image

like this image it allows multiple image selection from your local system

[image: Multiple File Selection]

and crop them by selecting Image Image Cropper

[image: Crop Single File from Selected Image List]